# Why is my iBeacon signal not detected every time it should send according to the interval?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I have a small BLE beacon which is configured to send iBeacon packets every 1000ms.

In my usecase i want to detect the signal on multiple recievers every time it is sent. However the detection is not reliable no matter which receiving device and software i use (phone, computer, raspberry). The signal is sometimes detected after 2 seconds, another time 5, 6 or whatever. It seems like there is no pattern behind it.

Also it seems that sometimes the signal is received on one receiver but not on the others while definetly being in range! Also the area i am testing in is not "problematic".

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% of beacon packets transmitted are ever received.  There are a number of reasons for this, including radio noise, packet collisions and channel hopping.  That said, the typical detection rate in a quiet radio environment is around 90 percent.

If you are seeing a much lower rate than this on multiple receivers I would check the transmitter.  First, use one of.your devices to transmit a software beacon (Android and iOS have free apps like Locate Beacon that do this.) If you get a higher detection rate with a different device transmitting, the issue may be your transmitter.

A few possible issues with it:

- Bad antenna sending out a very weak signal.  (Measure the received RSSI when you do get a detection and verify it is over -60 dBm)
- Weak transmitter power setting.  See if you can configure this higher.
- Advertising on wrong channels
- Advertising is stopped before packet can go out.  Try to leave the advertiser on for at least 2x the transmission rate to ensure at least on packet gets out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a large enough scan window for your scan interval so your receiver radio is actually turned on most of the time.

You could try to send advertising packets of the type ADV_NONCONN_IND (non-connectable and no scan response packet). That way if the receiver radio scans with 100% duty it should see the packet.

Otherwise if you use normal ADV_IND packets, then at least Android always waits for the SCAN_RSP packet before it sends anything to the scanning app. But if the are multiple scanners nearby, your peripheral can only respond to a single scanner's SCAN_REQ for each advertising packet. To avoid collisions of SCAN_REQ packets in the air, Bluetooth controllers also back off if they don't get a SCAN_RSP in return. If you use a BLE sniffer you can see all three kinds of packets and what happens when you have multiple scanners nearby.

Read the BLE Link Layer part of the Bluetooth Core specification for more details.